# Is horse riding the most dangerous sport you can do?

Tags: sport

I have heard more then once from people claiming that horse riding is the most dangerous sport you can be doing. But sound like it can't possible be true. It seems that sport like MMA where the goal is the hurt the opponent should be much more dangerous or possible rock climbing where one wrong step could mean you would fall to your death are should be more dangerous. So is it true that horse riding is the most dangerous sport?

Comment: As stands, this is missing a notable claim.  You assert that you've heard it more than once.  Please establish that this is a belief held by many people.  For example, a write up on a major media site, e.g. that of a magazine or a newspaper, would suffice.

Comment: Yes, statistics would be helpful.  Also note (from someone who does it) that "horse riding" covers a wide range of activities with different levels of risk: various forms of dressage & showing, hunting, jumping, polo, trail riding in the mountains, being a cowboy (yes, there still are such, and they use horses) in the American West, bronco riding in rodeo...

Comment: I found a quote claiming it to be so: ["It is one of the more dangerous sports, even though the safety equipment is very good," says Lucy Higginson, editor of Horse and Hound magazine.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/8339097.stm)

Comment: Define most dangerous. The sport where most people die while taking part, or with the most injuries? Anecdote says the most dangerous sport in England is crown green bowling  - the average age of players is 80.

Comment: "One of the more dangerous sports" is **absolutely not** the same as "the most dangerous sport". That quote doesn't support the claim at all.

Comment: @Lio Elbammalf:  Note that your quote seems to apply only to  "hunting, point-to-point and eventing", where "often quite sizeable obstacles are jumped", making it rather more dangerous than many other things you can do on a horse.

Comment: And it's less dangerous than base jumping?  I don't think so!